# How to get a user with most cars from mysql

Tags: mysql

Here, is just a foo example.

```
    id user        car       
------ --------------------- 
     1 kerN         eTrac     
     2 rSky         TClea     
     3 ataw         arahm     
     4 nvd          lengr     
     5 233          yzxq2     
     6 kerN         eTrac     
     7 keOr         gStri     
     8 odev         eunic     
     9 owsm         cward     
    10 ielr         cgabr     
    11 kerN         eTrac
```

From this table, I want to fetch the user with the most cars. In this case, the result should be the `user` `KerN` because they have 3 `eTrac` cars.

Comment: there are another users (yand, 1smg) which are associated with the car eTrac, so do you want all of them in final result?

Comment: Oh, sorry that was a mistake. :)

Comment: What if there are multiple users with the most number of cars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT user, COUNT(*) cars 
FROM table 
GROUP BY user 
ORDER BY cars desc
LIMIT 1;
```